# Is it possible to save a recorded audio file on iOS outside the App sandbox?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I am working on a WhatsApp kind of App. Users have the option of transferring Videos, Images, audio etc. Using ALAsset suite of framework, I can save the Images and Videos in the Device photo library etc. For Ex

```
- (void)writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL
                       completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

My Question is can I do something similar with a Audio file? Right now I am saving the Audio file within the sandbox itself say NSDocumentsDirectory etc. Is there a provision for saving a recorded audio file, received audio file in some kind of System storage like the Photo library for ex.? I don't want to bloat the App with regularly received Audio Files

Regards
0x6d6e

Comment: Or Another way of asking...Can I create a playlist programmatically and save it to iTunes. Idea being all recorded, received audio files goes into this playlist on iTunes, which the user can access outside the App. So that basically the audio files are not stored on the App Sandbox, but rather on some kind of global iTunes storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible till iOS 8. You are doing it right. You need to save the audio in your app sandbox. 
Work around can be converting audio file to video file, but that is not a win.

Comment: Okay. Kinda disappointing the APIs don't allow us to do this even though other assets like Pictures,videos can be saved. thanks

Comment: "No, this is not possible till iOS 8"  Are you saying that with iOS8 this is now possible?

Comment: I am not saying this. iOS 8 is included.